# VHDL on mac, basics

Tags: macos, emacs, vhdl, ghdl

I'm really new in this part of programming, I have tried to install ghdl and I'm not succeeding. I use Emacs to write c and c++ programs and I'm trying to use it to write vhdl too. Can someone help me to install ghdl? I know its a bad questions but I really need to install it and I'm getting frustrated, I tried http://ghdl.free.fr/ but the "read me" file was to much complicated, I barely know how to use shell (terminal) and there was a lot of instructions to write there. Well, I tried and still can't compile with ghdl, the terminal don't recognizes that command.

If someone could help with a good tutorial without complicating too much or post a link to the source, I will be very grateful. If you answer with a link to another question about that, believe me, I already read and it did not help me (probably because I'm really ignorante now).

Comment: The link you provided has a download button, which when clicked, transports you to a page that has a section that discusses OS X (i.e., Apple/Mac).  There is a standard dmg install on that page (that does not require knowing how to compile) -- is that not what you are looking for?  After installing, locate the binary and try executing the absolute path in the terminal to verify it works.  This question appears to have nothing to do with Emacs, so please edit the question to make it clear why Emacs is involved or remove the tag.

Comment: Please contact the GHDL mailing list [ghdl-discuss](https://mail.gna.org/listinfo/ghdl-discuss)

Comment: While waiting for the ghdl-0.33 package you can download [ghdl-0.31-mcode-darwin13.mpkg.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.31/OSX/ghdl-0.31-mcode-darwin13.mpkg.zip/download) ghdl-0.31 package from ghdl-updates on Sourceforge.  In the search bar add [ghdl] for searching for ghdl tagged posts. See [How do I compile and run a VHDL program on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069939/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-vhdl-program-on-mac), Also see [GHDL’s on line documentation](http://ghdl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: (Very funny Paebbels.  In the upcoming 0.33 package I suggest coming here first.)

Comment: ghdl-0.33 can be downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases/tag/v0.33) or [ghdl-updates](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.33/) (Sourceforge). Installation is simplified only requiring installing the Xcode command line tools as a prerequisite to use, providing a linker. That's easy, too. In a terminal entering the shell command `xcode-select --install` opens a dialog. There's also a [GTKWave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/) OS X app [download](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/gtkwave.zip).

Answer (score 0):

That site ([ghdl.free.fr](http://ghdl.free.fr)) had (at the time I answered) a very old release of ghdl. Now updated to point to the new Github releases page, thanks David for pointing it out!

Look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/ for a much newer one (ghdl-0.33) with far fewer bugs and fairly good VHDL-2008 support. In addition no the source, there are OS-X packages for ghdl-0.31.

However I recommend ghdl-0.33 (released in October, OS-X packages are being tested, but I'm not sure if they are on the site yet.) These packages are prepared by another regular StackOverflow poster, I expect he'll be along any minute to correct any details I've mis-remembered.

Also available from [github](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl) as source, not sure if there are binary releases there yet.

The OS-X packages for 0.33 seem not to be uploaded yet, but should happen it the next few days. Meanwhile here is [ghdl-0.31 for OS-X](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.31/OSX/)

Comment: Here is the GitHub release page for [0.33](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases) :).

Comment: Excellent ... but no mac packages yet.

Comment: Give me a day or two and I'll release the ghdl-0.33-llvm-darwin13 package (It may only show up on the github releases page). It's tested, I'm just testing the package scripts now.

Comment: Tristan has been updating ghdl.free.fr.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing ghdl-0.33 for OS X (10.9, 10.10, 10.11)

ghdl-0.33 can be downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases/tag/v0.33) or [ghdl-updates](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.33/) (Sourceforge).

Installation requires installing the Xcode command line tools which provide a linker as a prerequisite to use.

If not already installed, in a terminal entering the shell command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This will open an installation dialog allowing downloading and installation of the Xcode Command Line Tools developement environment.

There's also the [GTKWave](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/) waveform viewer with an OS X app [download](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/gtkwave.zip). Unzip it and move the app to your Applications folder.

Note that both ghdl and GTKWave are open source released under  GNU Public License (GPL) terms. Neither the ghdl installation package nor the GTKWave app are signed and require you to bypass Gatekeeper to install. The ghdl-0.33-llvm-darwin13 package installer requires administrative rights to guarantee permissions can be set in /usr/local. See the first pane of the installer dialog.

The good news is that you can build and install ghdl or GTKWave yourself should you not trust unsigned software. The second pane on the ghdl-0.33-llvm-darwin13.pkg installer dialog gives complete directions for doing so and the process is also streamlined from previous releases.